# VS2008 JIT debugging call stack shows only system calls

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am looking at a un-handled exception via a JIT debugger of VS2008. Can anyone give me some pointer what is going on? Call stack isn't pointing anywhere in code. And pretty sure the code tries to catch all exceptions.

```
msvcr90.dll!_crt_debugger_hook(int _Reserved=0) Line 65
msvcr90.dll!_invoke_watson(const wchar_t* pszExpression=0x00000000, const wchar_t* pszFunction=0x00000000 .... 
msvcr90.dll!fgets(char* string=0x30ebf7c4, int count=15, _iobuf* str=0x00000000) Line 55 + 0x20 bytes
MyProgram.exe!00443faf()
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for MyProgram.exe]
MyProgram.exe!0046b639()
ws2_32.dll!71c044c0()
ws2_32.dll!71c023ec()
ws2_32.dll!71c0357b()
msvcr90.dll!malloc(unsigned int size=0) Line 163 + 0x5f bytes
ffffffff()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on with no source code, but ...

The following entry suggests that a NULL `FILE*` has been passed to `fgets()`:

```
fgets(char* string=0x30ebf7c4, int count=15, _iobuf* str=0x00000000)
```

I can see `ws2_32.dll` in your call stack, so I'm assuming that you're using sockets somewhere.

At a guess I would suggest that a remote socket endpoint has closed and you are trying to read from it.

If this is a Release build, you can change the project settings so that you generate a `.PDB` which you can then use to get some more sensible information from the dump.

If you can post more code or comment on the above, it might be possible to help further.

Comment: Yes it is a release build. Will try to generate a PDB file and wait for the next crash.